# Re-arrange order of iOS select menu with CSS

Tags: css, ios

I have a dropdown with span elements on desktop. I use CSS Flexbox to re-arrange order of the elements:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.child {
order: 0;
}
.child.disabled {
order: 1;
}
```

This works well - but on iOS the re-arrange doesnt work. Is it possible to target this as well, or does it needs to be done server-side?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you’re using a [browser that supports `order`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order#browser_compatibility)?

Comment: Ive tried both Safari and Chrome on iPhone. But im not even sure im targeting the iOS select menu at all.

Comment: Tested this on browser stack and works on ipad pro 12.9 and iphone 14 using safari: https://jsfiddle.net/e410oqa2/

Comment: try using 1 and 2

Comment: @Skin_phil Why? [Ordering flex items](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#the_order_property) puts items in ordinal groups based on integers. 0 and 1 are just as valid as 1 and 2.

Comment: yes but 0 is the default, so it might fight with another element, your example is very limited, you should post something where we can reproduce the behaviour

Comment: You realize Im talking about the iPhone scrolling menu right? It works well on desktop, any browser but on the iPhone it transforms the menu to a scroll menu. This is what Im refering to.

Comment: @Jerry No, this is not clear. You say you have a “dropdown with span elements”, not a `<select>` with `<option>`s which would actually be rendered like this picker menu on the iPhone. You do not show any HTML, so all we can do is guess what these CSS rules apply to. A [Stack Snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212) would clarify that. An actual `<select>` does _not_ offer cross-browser control over its rendering.

Comment: I wrote I use Span elements on DESKTOP, and that my styling doesnt affect the iOS SELECT menu (see title of thread) - and how to arrange the items and if it possible to target the iOS select menu with CSS. And a stack snippet.. Im talking about IOS own rendered select menu. I cant use a Stack snippet for that, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Jerry Yes, you can use a Stack Snippet (or at least a code block) to demonstrate what _your_ code looks like. But okay, the “on desktop” part was a bit confusing because then the question is: Why not just use the `<span>` version on iOS, too? As I said, this will be the only option, since a proper `<select>` will be rendered by the system with no user control over how it’s rendered.